# Api to trim the 12 digit phone number to ten digits?

Tags: api

we have issue where we have an api which accepts only 10 digits. But in our SMS panel we have made to store the 12 digits.ex:910123456789 And now client side it's triggering an error saying where it accepts only 10 digits. So can i trim the first two numbers and send it through an api?

Comment: you forget to mention development enviroment information.!!

Comment: @anurag The panel has been developed under php.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using a simple built in function in php (as your comment says you are using php) as below:

```
<?php
echo substr("910123456789",10);
//output will be 0123456789
?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php